# Get the result of the comparation without jump in nasm

Tags: nasm

I would like to compare two value in nasm, but i don't want to jump afterwards.

So if i have something like this:

```
bool a = (1 < 2) && (2 < 3);
```

What is the shortest method to do this in nasm?

With regards.

Answer (score 1):

There is an instructions cmov* (conditional move).

```
mov al, 0
cmp 1, 2
cmovl al, 1

mov bl, 0
cmp 2, 3
cmovl bl, 1

and al, bl

; answer is in al
```

cmovl - move if less.
I am not sure if it's the shortest way.